# Make division fill the remaining space in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

There are three `ul` tags in the code below. The first one's float is left (by default), the third one's float is set to right (using `navbar-right` class).
Now I need the second `ul` (named `#ThisUL`) fill the remaining space between two other `ul` tags.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="border:1px solid red;">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="ThisUL" class="nav navbar-nav" style="background-color:pink;">
                    <li><input type="text" /></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="border:1px solid red;">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add this code? `ul {margin: 0px auto; width: 200px;}`

But if you want this to work, you need to write a width.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this layout simply and efficiently with [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Add this to your CSS:

```
div.container-fluid > div:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#ThisUL {
  flex: 1;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xxwzqwga/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="border:1px solid red;">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <ul id="ThisUL" class="nav navbar-nav" style="background-color:pink;">
                <li><input type="text" /></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="border:1px solid red;">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```